# What ASP.NET book would you recommend to a newcomer?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to learn ASP.NET and just wanted some input as to which book to read.

Comment: Are you a newcomer to programming in general, web development, or just ASP.NET?  What's your background?

Comment: I am a newcomer to programming in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found books from WROX useful (the covers are lame though):

- [Beginning ASP.NET 3.5: In C# and VB (Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047018759X)
- [Professional ASP.NET 3.5: In C# and VB (Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470187573)

O'Rielly books aren't bad either:

- [ASP.NET in a Nutshell, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005202)
- [Programming ASP.NET, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600916X)

Comment: I started out on the P2PWROX books as well and suplimented with examples/demos/tutorials on (www.)ASP.NET  website.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick selection of a few good ones I can suggest for easy intro's and good writting style.

[Andrew Troelson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002EZZ5FY) gives a nice front to back on the full 3.5 framework . Its not ASP.NET specific or too deef of a dive on anything, but can be a nice general lookup for lots of things you run into. It also gives a decent backstory of the framework and language.

If your diving into ASP.NET for the first time, you may as well do it right. The [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223839) book gives a step by step as many others, but focuses on some of the performance side and options to consider for different site types and common pitfalls.

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newcomer to programming in general and want to learn asp.net mvc. Get this book:
[ASP.NET MVC Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690308). Its for beginners and a good book to start. If you are experienced programmer - [Steven Sandersons book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) is the best choice. So I would recommend get ASP.NET MVC 2.0 cookbook to start and Steve Sandersons book to get deeper and become a real master.