# How to show selected index on top in DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, list.selectedvalue

Actually i am displaying months in first list on selecting the month if the value of month is other than 31 it shows at top otherwise it shows jan at top how to show the other one?

Here is code:

Code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue); i++)
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("" + i));
    }
}
```

Designer source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="31">Jan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="29">Feb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="31">Mar</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="30">April</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="31">May</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="30">June</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="31">July</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Problem is:

If i select march or may or any item with value 31 jan is shown at to while in other case the selected one is shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot  abatishchev u help me but i am beginner  so i could not much understand  the code but i really thank u people who are helping me to learn the asp.net.

Comment: My property window get de-attached from the visual studio(Means not showing it in auto-hide mode) how to make it shown in auto-hide mode

Comment: Indeed you accepted a correct but not the best solution. What for are you hard-coding month numbers when you can do not do that ;) Use `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` to determine the number from current year and selected month index + 1 (Jan : 1, Feb : 2, Mar : 3, etc)

Comment: Drag the property window to the side you want and choose one of the modes it will ask you for

Comment: @abatishchev: Could u guide me the books or sites which helps me to understand asp.net and learn it . And if u know any site which gives daily assignment for learning please suggest.  THANKS!!!!!!!!! in advance

Comment: The best what I can recommend you: practice more and more, don't afraid to make mistakes and ask questions here, on SO. Have you read CLR via C# (about .NET in genera)? Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531576/what-asp-net-book-would-you-recommend-to-a-newcomer) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120514/best-book-to-learn-asp-net)

Comment: I have opened Both link. But could u provide the link for any free resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values of ListItems should be unique.

Default selected item is Jan (value = 31), so everything will work fine when you click on items with another values (29 and 30).

When you click on Mar, May, July (value = 31), then Jan becomes selected.

To achieve the behavior you want, use another approach.

---

The best solution is:

```
using System.Linq;

int count =  DateTime.DaysInMonth(
     DateTime.Today.Year,
     int.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex + 1)); // sic!

DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(
    Enumerable.Range(1, count)
        .Select(i => new ListItem(i.ToString()))
        .ToArray());
```

So you don't need to hard-code anything! Everything is already in .NET FCL. Just determine month's number from it's index into the list.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and this is not an uncommon problem.  On post-back asp.net will show the first item in the list with the selected value.  The only way I've found around it is to make all of the values unique, such as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Jan-31">Jan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Feb-29">Feb</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Mar-31">Mar</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="April-30">April</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="May-31">May</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="June-30">June</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="July-31">July</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in your DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged event use a string.split on '-' to get the day count value.

Comment: My property window get de-attached from the visual studio(Means not showing it in auto-hide mode) how to make it shown in auto-hide mode