# Membership.CreateUser returns DuplicateUserName when the email is duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have been working on this frustrating bug for a few days now and can not seem to put my finger on it. I am attempting to create a user on an ASP.NET website using the following code:

```
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                                MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(UserName.Text, Password1.Text, Email1.Text, SecQ.Text, SecA.Text, true, out createStatus);

                                switch (createStatus)
                                {
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "The user account was successfully created!";
                                        CreateAccountResults.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                                        break;
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "There already exists a user with this email address.";
                                        break;
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "There already exists a user with this username.";
                                        break;
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "There email address you provided in invalid.";
                                        break;
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "There security answer was invalid.";
                                        break;
                                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "The password you provided is invalid. It must be seven characters long and have at least one non-alphanumeric character.";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        CreateAccountResults.Text = "There was an unknown error; the user account was NOT created.";
                                        break;
```

However, if I have "Email" a unique column in the database, it will return duplicateUserName if I enter an email address that is already taken (Instead of returning DuplicateEmail) I have attempted to Google and even just read over the code trying to understand the issue but I can not seem to locate exactly where it is going wrong.

Here is the attached stored procedure called when attempting to create the user:

```
    USE [gladiatorial]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser]    Script Date: 07/05/2011 20:40:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser]
    @ApplicationName                        nvarchar(256),
    @UserName                               nvarchar(256),
    @Password                               nvarchar(128),
    @PasswordSalt                           nvarchar(128),
    @Email                                  nvarchar(256),
    @PasswordQuestion                       nvarchar(256),
    @PasswordAnswer                         nvarchar(128),
    @IsApproved                             bit,
    @CurrentTimeUtc                         datetime,
    @CreateDate                             datetime = NULL,
    @UniqueEmail                            int      = 0,
    @PasswordFormat                         int      = 0,
    @UserId                                 uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ApplicationId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT  @ApplicationId = NULL

    DECLARE @NewUserId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT @NewUserId = NULL

    DECLARE @IsLockedOut bit
    SET @IsLockedOut = 0

    DECLARE @LastLockoutDate  datetime
    SET @LastLockoutDate = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptCount int
    SET @FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart  datetime
    SET @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount int
    SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart  datetime
    SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @NewUserCreated bit
    DECLARE @ReturnValue   int
    SET @ReturnValue = 0

    DECLARE @ErrorCode     int
    SET @ErrorCode = 0

    DECLARE @TranStarted   bit
    SET @TranStarted = 0

    IF( @@TRANCOUNT = 0 )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET @TranStarted = 1
    END
    ELSE
        SET @TranStarted = 0

    EXEC dbo.aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication @ApplicationName, @ApplicationId OUTPUT

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    SET @CreateDate = @CurrentTimeUtc

    SELECT  @NewUserId = UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE LOWER(@UserName) = LoweredUserName AND @ApplicationId = ApplicationId
    IF ( @NewUserId IS NULL )
    BEGIN
        SET @NewUserId = @UserId
        EXEC @ReturnValue = dbo.aspnet_Users_CreateUser @ApplicationId, @UserName,  @CreateDate, @NewUserId OUTPUT
        SET @NewUserCreated = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @NewUserCreated = 0
        IF( @NewUserId <> @UserId AND @UserId IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = 6
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF( @ReturnValue = -1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 10
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT UserId
                  FROM   dbo.aspnet_Membership
                  WHERE  @NewUserId = UserId ) )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 6
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    SET @UserId = @NewUserId

    IF (@UniqueEmail = 1)
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM  dbo.aspnet_Membership m WITH ( UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK )
                    WHERE ApplicationId = @ApplicationId AND LoweredEmail = LOWER(@Email)))
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = 7
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    IF (@NewUserCreated = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Users
        SET    LastActivityDate = @CreateDate
        WHERE  @UserId = UserId
        IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = -1
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Membership
                ( ApplicationId,
                  UserId,
                  Password,
                  PasswordSalt,
                  Email,
                  LoweredEmail,
                  PasswordQuestion,
                  PasswordAnswer,
                  PasswordFormat,
                  IsApproved,
                  IsLockedOut,
                  CreateDate,
                  LastLoginDate,
                  LastPasswordChangedDate,
                  LastLockoutDate,
                  FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
                  FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
                  FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
                  FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )
         VALUES ( @ApplicationId,
                  @UserId,
                  @Password,
                  @PasswordSalt,
                  @Email,
                  LOWER(@Email),
                  @PasswordQuestion,
                  @PasswordAnswer,
                  @PasswordFormat,
                  @IsApproved,
                  @IsLockedOut,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @LastLockoutDate,
                  @FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
                  @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
                  @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
                  @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @TranStarted = 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END

    RETURN 0

Cleanup:

    IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @TranStarted = 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    RETURN @ErrorCode

END
```

I would appreciate it if someone could please point me in the right direction to get this resolve. I have a feeling it is going to be something extremely minor that I have overlooked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the attribute `requiresUniqueEmail` to `false` in your `Web.Config` file if you don't want unique emails for users. 
Eg

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <add 
      name="SqlProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
      connectionStringName="SqlServices"
      applicationName="MyApplication"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response, Eranga. Can you recommend any good material to learn ASP?

Once again, thank you very  much.

Matt

Comment: There are plenty of answers here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531576/what-asp-net-book-would-you-recommend-to-a-newcomer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973275/what-is-the-best-book-for-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure checks whether a record with that user name exists before checking the email address.  If you are using the email address as the user name, it returns a value corresponding to `MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName` and never gets around to checking the email address.